# How to use nested navigation stacks in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Below is my navigation structure.

*Drawer Navigator (

- Dashboard
  StackNavigator({

  1. Login
  2. Welcome
     })
- Profile
  StackNavigator({

  1. Profile
     })
     )*

**I have a logout button on the Profile page and on click on it I want to take the user back to the login page.**

Please help.

Below is my Navigation.js file

```
const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: LoginScreen,
    DashboardScreen: {
        screen: DashboardScreen,
    },
    CaptureWeightScreen: {
        screen: CaptureWeightScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerBackTitle: " ",
            headerTintColor: "#000"
        }
    }
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Dashboard'
    }
});
const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ProfileScreen: ProfileScreen
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Profile'
    }
});
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    DashboardNavigator: LoginNavigator,
    ProfileNavigator: ProfileNavigator,
    
}, { 
    drawerBackgroundColor: Constants.buttonColor 
});
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: "Login", params: { } })`

Is the answer.

Thanks